# Python gui table whose cells are drop down lists with dynamic content based on the content of other drop-down-list-cells of the same gui-table

Tags: validation, python-3.x, listview, qtableview

I am trying to port to Python 3.x a small gui application that I have written in Matlab.
The app contains a Matlab uitable, with which you can program bitfields of registers of a microcontroller. Actually you can create a panel which groups some register-bitfields that are important to you for debugging at a specific point in time (kind-of a watch window in a compiler IDE).

It looks like this:
[Gui Table used to write to register bitfields of a microcontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7i87.png)

So, each row of the table can be used to program a specific register bitfield.
There are 4 columns:
 1. Register name (drop down list)
 2. Bitfield name (drop down list)
 3. Value to write (string)
 4. Format (Hex or Dec drop down list, irrelevant here)

In order to use this application, one first clicks on the register name drop down list, where all registers are shown (detail: using a text box one can apply filters to narrow down the list size).
When the register is selected, the drop down list of the bitfield column updates automatically so that it contains only the bitfields of the chosen register. This happens with the help of a callback function.
Then, the user has to enter a value and a format, and only if all cells contain valid content, then a register write command is issued (via some debugger interface).

This worked OKish; sometimes the bitfields list was actually the one of the previous register added in the table, but this could be detected and have the entry cleared so that the user can try again. Also when the number of rows becomes very high and scroll bars appear, then if the user tries to enter a register at the bottom, every time they click on the drop down list, they can choose an entry and then the scroll bar position will automatically change showing the beginning of the table. This makes the process of entering registers quite cumbersome. As far as I know, the uitable of Matlab did not have accessible properties to control this behavior.

Since I am a hw engineer with limited sw technologies knowledge, I am wondering if there is a natural way to support this in Python 3.x, say with some structured (e.g. xml) data container that can naturally map to a gui component, without so much callback programming and data validation. The ideal behavior would be that the user starts to type directly at the register name drop down list (not possible in Matlab), and dynamically gets a filtered version of the register names list.

I am completely new to python, just installed Anaconda. I have found some interesting classes in PyQt:
QListView Class, 
QListWidget Class, 
QTableView Class, 
QTableWidget Class.

However, I would like to have the combined functionality of the tableview with a listview, as is the case with the uitable in Matlab. Or even better, a text edit input that turns into a drop down list after typing a few letters.

The [pyqtgraph.tablewidget](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/tablewidget.html) seems to augment the functionality of QTableWidget, but I think this is still not what I need.

So, if the above is not possible, or would involve heavy programming, maybe all I need is to change approach and have a single separate search box with autocompletion, which looks into a "flattened" version of the registers database, and returns results in the form my_register_1.my_bitfield_1 (maybe allowing the user to search simultaneously at both register and bitfield names). When the user clicks on one item of the "autocompletion list", then the selected entry is mapped to the currently selected line in the tableview, adding both the register name and bitfield in read-only table cells. The "value to write" cell should still be editable, and when it gets valid data it should trigger register write command...

I would appreciate if you could guide me where to look. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Qt model/view](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/modelview.html) architecture.  This allows you to have a representation of your data (the "model"), which is separate from how that data is represented (the "view").  So you set up a table of data, and then set up a view to represent that data.  When you switch between different data sets, you tell the view to display the new data set.  The tutorial I linked to explains this in some detail